# /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

I got this error message below:

```
ld: file not found: ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20UICommon.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

it told me that `libThree20UICommon.a` is missing.
But I've remove `Three20` from my project and code related to Three20.
is there anything else i have to do with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the project setting "other linker flags" does not contain any three20 paths.

Answer (score 0):

For the same error ..
 what i did is..
i deleted red colored framework/library from framework list and add the same from build settings again.. it works