# facing strange issue with xcode project opening

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

My project directory is: Developer/Examples/MyPhoneGame/MyPhoneGame.xcodeproj
But i could not open this proj. If i rename the directory to something else, the proj get open but failed to compiled.

I am using Xcode 4.2. What will be the reason?

Any help?

Comment: it must be giving somw warning for not opening the Project?

Comment: Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: @ chetan rane :- Thanks and +1 for Simple Question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at these Posts.. hope they help :-

[Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460918/command-developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-gcc-4-2)
[/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687548/developer-platforms-iphonesimulator-platform-developer-usr-bin-llvm-gcc-4-2-fai)

Comment: so the trick works for me....i was deleting preference in wrong way....(/Library/Preferences folder)...but the trick is you should clear all preferences from xcode (xcode-preferences-Derived Data) clear all and set it to Relative path

Comment: Great!!! i am Happy it helps you....by the way... recognizing problem and having it solved is a great enjoyment.... you can say Thank you by upvoting the answer.. :D